# Is it possible to execute/run cucumber test scripts from a network drive?

Tags: ruby, networking, cucumber, network-drive

I'm needing to store cucumber test scripts in a shared network drive in order for teams in other timezones to be able to run these scripts from a shared network drive rather than their local directory.  I am now running into what seems like the same issue that you would see if you try to use the change directory 'cd' command in command prompt (cmd.exe) example and error message below:

```
cd \\myserver\myshare
Error Message:  UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
```

Now, I can get around this first part by using the 'pushd' and 'popd' commands and the cucumber command I'd like to run is:

```
cucumber --format html --out GoogleSearch_#{Time.new.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')}.html
```

I have also tried putting this code inside of a ruby .rb file and then trying to use a ruby system command to get the cucumber script to run but this also does not work:

Example:

```
Dir::chdir("//myserver/myshare") do
  system("cucumber --format html --out GoogleSearch_#{Time.new.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')}.html")
end
```

I'm now out of ideas :( any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not use version control (eg git) to share your test scripts. Failing that, sounds like mapping the network share to a letter (z: and so on) might work

Comment: Hey Frederick thanks for the reply not sure why I didn't try that first. I had to make a few modifications to my script but ultimately mapping the drive resolved the issue. Thanks for the quick response!